# Error: Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.\par

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\pagestyle{myheadings}

%% Generan la fuente del doumento, Arial
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif


%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{lucidabr}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs,keyval,color,
psfrag,multirow,lscape,overcite}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb,rotating}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[sc]{caption2}
\usepackage{float,array}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage{calrsfs} % beatiful curly letters
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{RCS}


%\usepackage[dvips,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,pdftitle={RICA},plainpages=false,pdfauthor={Ricardo Vallejo},colorlinks=true,hypertexnames=false,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,filecolor=red]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showkeys} % este paquete  muestra en el dvi las claves asignadas en el paquete de tex
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

%Espacio para definir los nuevos entornos
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{teor}[prop]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corol}{Corolario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conj}[prop]{Conjetura}
\newtheorem{afirm}{Afirmación}
\newtheorem{problema}{Problema}
\newtheorem{algor}{Algoritmo}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ejem}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem*{caso}{caso}

\addto{\captionsspanish}{\def\chaptername{}}  % evita que salga la palabra capítulo en las cabeceras de capítulo
\renewcommand{\captionlabeldelim}{.}

\newpsobject{grilla}{psgrid}{subgriddiv=10, griddots=10,
gridlabels=6pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm} \setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\def\bmod{\mskip-\medmuskip \mkern5mu
\mathbin{\rm m\acute od} \penalty900 \mkern5mu \mskip-\medmuskip}
\def\pmod#1{\allowbreak \mkern18mu ({\rm m\acute od}\,\,#1)}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{m\acute{a}x}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{l\acute{\i}m}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

%\linespread{1.35}
\parindent=10pt
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pretolerance=20000 \tolerance=3000
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Universidad ICESI}\\
\textbf{Departamento de Matemáticas y Estadística}\\
\textbf{Álgebra y Funciones}\\
\textbf{Docente: \emph{Ronald Galeano}}\\
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{-3cm}
{\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace{13cm}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{logoicesi}
\end{flushright}

\end{figure}
\vspace{0,5cm}
\textbf{Nombre y Código:}\\
\vspace{0,35cm}
\hspace{3.4cm} ..................................................................................\\
\vspace{0,35cm}
\hspace{3.5cm}..................................................................................\\
\vspace{0,35cm}
\hspace{3.5cm}..................................................................................\\
\vspace{0,35cm}
\hspace{3.5cm}..................................................................................

\begin{center}
\large\textbf{Taller en Clase Sección 1.3}\\
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lleve a cabo las operaciones indicadas y simplifique.
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item[A.] $(x^{3}+6x^{2}+4x+7)-(3x^{2}+2x-4)$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[B.] $5(3t-4)-(t^{2}+2)-2t(t-3)$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[C.] $x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left( \sqrt{x}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) $  
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[D.] $(3x^{2}y+7xy^{2})(x^{2}y^{3}-2y^{2})$
\end{itemize}
%\end{multicols}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item Factorice la expresión completamente. 
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item[A.] $(x-1)(x+2)^{2}-(x-1)^{2}(x+2)$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[B.] $(x+1)^{3}x-2(x+1)^{2}x^{2}+x^{3}(x+1)$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[C.] $t^{4}+t^{2}-2$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[D.] $2m^{3}+4m^{2}+m+2$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[E.] $(x-1)^{\frac{7}{2}}-(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item[F.] $(a^{2}+2a)^{2}-2(a^{2}+2a)-3$
\end{itemize}
%\end{multicols}



\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.\par

Comment: Update -- the error is long gone in a current tex system. If you have miktex, update as user *and* as admin.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Besides the fact that you use an image we do not have, I don't an error like that. I get a warning about some groups not being closed but that is it. Tested on TeXLive 2018, updated this week. (3) Why are you hand numerating items using itemize? Youy might want to have a look at the `enumitem` package as a replacement for the `enumerate` package you already load. Also use the `geometry` package to set margins instead of doing it manually like this.

Comment: Please try to be more specific with your question titles. We want this to be a resource that’s useful to other people searching for the same question.

Comment: Thank you very much Ulrike Fischer; it works